# Access - table in design view is almost unreadable

Tags: ms-access

Few weeks ago access start show text in design view in light grey. When the field is active the text is almost white which make it almost unreadable. I tried to google it and went through option in access but I cannot find anything how to change it... [image]

Comment: Does it just happen on one table or do all the tables look like this? Even newly created tables?

Comment: No I have the same issue for older database or newly created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, you could try changing your office theme settings.

file->options->General

[image]

So, this may well be your windows settings. Try a different office theme, or even try using "system" settings for the above.

Comment: Well it looks like this did the trick :) It was OK for dark theme as well in the past so not sure what happened... Thank you :)